# How to set thread name in TestNG

Tags: testng

I'm running my tests in parallel.
TestNG by default set name of the threads as `TestNG`
It makes difficult to browse through log files and differentiate between the messages.

TestNG [javadocs](http://testng.org/javadoc/) is of no help.

Is there any way I can set the Thread Name or Thread Id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the thread name in my tests.  For example, see how I did it [IN THIS PROJECT](http://djangofan.github.io/simple-selenium-builder-framework/).  Basically, all my Log4j messages (as well as testNG reporter messages) show the thread id in them.

Here is a basic example, which makes it easy to show thread id in the standard output.   You can also put the threadid in the html standard out using the `Reporter` class.  Unfortunately you can't put threadid on the test name in the HTML report unless you write a custom reporter (which I did in my link to my project above):

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ParallelMethodTest 
{
    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("Before test-method. Thread id is: " + id);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodsOne() {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("Simple test-method One. Thread id is: " + id);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodsTwo() {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("Simple test-method Two. Thread id is: " + id);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println("After test-method. Thread id is: " + id);
    }
}
```

Comment: No content, basically [only a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). [Also related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer). Downvoted until fixed.

Comment: This is good but we also needed to include code for the testng.xml file that would run this code in parallel: <suite name="Test-method Suite" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" >
    <test name="Test-method test" group-by-instances="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="ParallelMethodTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setName() function to provide a custom name for your thread.

Following is an example in JAVA to set Thread name:

```
Thread.currentThread().setName("Thread 1");
```

Above line will set your current thread name to "Thread 1".